# How to update database with spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to update my database (postgresql) in my spring boot app with some form information that I will get from an angular 8 form. How can I complete the code below to do so ?

PS : I have no access to the front devs, so no access to the angular code.

**My Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "person")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    private int idPerson;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "alive")
    private Boolean alive;
}
```

**My Mapping class :**

```
@Data
public class PersonForm {

    @NotBlank
    private String idPerson;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    private boolean alive;

}
```

**My Repository :**

```
@Repository
public interface IPersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, String> {

}
```

**My Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "person")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {this.personService = personService;}

    @PostMapping(value = "savePerson")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<PersonEntity> savePerson(@RequestBody final PersonForm form) {

        return ?
    }
}
```

**My Service :**

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonRepository personRepository;

    public IPersonRepository(IPersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }
```

Comment: I did, but I could'nt find the best one to help me !

Comment: Did you check angular code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is enough to work.

Have others ways to do it, this is only example that complements your line of thought.

If you get a compilation error or another error, let me know :)

First you need create your object `PersonEntity` and sent it to your service.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "person")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {this.personService = personService;}

    @PostMapping(value = "savePerson")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<PersonEntity> savePerson(@RequestBody final PersonForm form) {

        PersonEntity entity = new PersonEntity(form);
        entity = personService.save(entity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(entity);

    }
}
```

In your service, you will call the `save` method from repository implementation.

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonRepository personRepository;

    public IPersonRepository(IPersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public PersonEntity save(PersonEntity entity) {
        return personRepository.save(entity);
    }

}
```

After it you will create `ResponseEntity` in the method `PersonController.savePerson`